# alternate colors onClick

Tags: function, colors, alternate

I am working on a javascript function that will cause the background color of a div element to alternate between lavenderblush and cyan every time the button is pressed.

When I press the button once, it will change colors, but will not change back when pressed a second time. How do I fix this?

Comment: check your logic ... if color NOT lavender, change it to cyan, otherwise if it is cyan, change it to lavender ... once it's cyan, it's not lavender, so it's always set to cyan from then on ... try `!==` in the `else if`

Comment: i tried that too, but it didn't work

Comment: Of course that didn't work - sorry about the misinformation

Comment: there are presumably three possible values for bgcolor ... "", "cyan", "lavenderblush" ... what is the logic ... "cyan"->"lavender", "'lavender"->"cyan" and ""->??? ... so ... change !== "lavender" to === "lavender" ... and change the `else if...` to just an `else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, background colour can be one of 3 values, "cyan", "lavenderblush", *anything else*

Now, if the logic is

```
Current          Changes to
--------------   -------------
cyan             lavenderblush
lavenderblush    cyan
*anything else*  lavenderblush
```

Then the code should be

```
var style = document.getElementById('new').style;
if (style.backgroundColor === "lavenderblush") {
    style.backgroundColor = "cyan";
} else {
    style.backgroundColor = "lavenderblush";
}
```

Or, if the logic is

```
Current          Changes to
--------------   -------------
cyan             lavenderblush
lavenderblush    cyan
*anything else*  cyan
```

Then the code is

```
var style = document.getElementById('new').style;
if (style.backgroundColor === "cyan") {
    style.backgroundColor = "lavenderblush";
} else {
    style.backgroundColor = "cyan";
}
```

However, if the logic is

```
Current          Changes to
--------------   -------------
cyan             lavenderblush
lavenderblush    cyan
*anything else*  *do not change*
```

Then the code is

```
var style = document.getElementById('new').style;
if (style.backgroundColor === "cyan") {
    style.backgroundColor = "lavenderblush";
} else if (style.backgroundColor === "lavenderblush") {
    style.backgroundColor = "cyan";
}
```

Here's the first "logic" as a runnable snippet

```js
function Replace() {
    var style = document.getElementById('new').style;
    if (style.backgroundColor === "lavenderblush") {
        style.backgroundColor = "cyan";
    } else {
        style.backgroundColor = "lavenderblush";
    }
}
document.getElementById('Replace').addEventListener('click', Replace);
```

```html
<button id="Replace">Click</button>
<div id="new">NEW</div>
```

Comment: the logic and code make complete sense, but for some reason its not working. :/

Comment: Snippet works - so, perhaps you're doing something wrong

Comment: it works, I tried it on an online compiler and it worked perfectly. Maybe its just my browser. Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: `online compiler` ??? huh? javascript is interpreted not compiled. `Maybe its just my browser` - which browser is that?

Comment: i used JSFiddle to test the code online. and chrome is my browser

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier and use the `classList API` to handle style changes programmatically.

Specifically checkout `.toggle()`. It's a native solution. No Deps needed and it's just much simpler logic to deal with all around. Cheers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: No mention of CSS? changes to class are pointless without appropriate CSS styles - and there's the usual *warning: older Internet Exploder is different* caveat's with classList API :p